# Linux cut and grep

Tags: linux, cut

I have a task which I can not solve by my own.

A file is given with countries and 3 columns. name, capital city, number of inhabitants. Now I have to find(and list) all country-names with a capital city that starts with a 'B'. If possible I would like to solve the problem just with cut and grep and not with awk and sed. 
So far, no problem to find all capitals which start with a 'B'

```
cut -d, -f2 country.txt | grep ^B
```

So I list all capitals which start with a 'B'. But I have to list all countries and not just the capitals!

Thank you.

```
Germany,Berlin,80000000
Austria,Vienna,800000
Spain,Madrid,49000000
Serbia,Belgrad,7400000
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense to use `grep` and `cut` and squeeze its options until the solution breaks because of a B somewhere in another field. Use `awk` alone, as it handles these things in a way more simple syntax:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /^B/ {print $1}' file
```

This checks if the 2nd field starts with a B. If so, it prints the first field.

It returns:

```
Germany
Serbia
```

It also works well for the file  you mention in your answer.

```
$ cat file
Germany,Berlin,catholics,80000000
Austria,Vienna,catholics,800000
Spain,Madrid,catholics,49000000
Serbia,Belgrad,catholics,7400000 
India,New-Delhi,Buddhism,1230000000
$ awk -F, '$2 ~ /^B/ {print $1}' file
Germany
Serbia
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the search first and cut after

```
$ grep ,B file | cut -d, -f1

Germany
Serbia
```

if there may be spaces after comma,

```
$ grep ', *B' file | cut -d, -f1
```

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you for your answers. 
For that case it would work with: 

$ grep ,B file | cut -d, -f1

But what if I have several columns and add the religion
If I grep now with ",B" it doesn't work because I search on all fields. 

Germany,Berlin,catholics,80000000
Austria,Vienna,catholics,800000
Spain,Madrid,catholics,49000000
Serbia,Belgrad,catholics,7400000 
India,New-Delhi,Buddhism,1230000000

But I want just - like before - search all capitals with B* - and show the countryname

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cut -d, -f2,1,3 country.txt | grep ^B
```

But this will change the order of columns.
Or you can invert that and print only country names, without other fields:

```
grep ",B" country.txt | cut -d, -f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep` you can use Perl-like regex, then `cut` is not needed:

```
$  grep -oP '^\w+(?=,B)' country.txt 
Germany
Serbia
```

This is called a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).